# Behaviour of ruby with regards to numerical exactness (Scheme comparison)

Tags: ruby, lisp, scheme

In Ruby (1.9), are numbers *always* considered exact?  I know Ruby does some fairly complex stuff with numbers under the hood, since you can do crazy things like ask for 1 trillion to the power of 1 trillion and you will get an answer (after waiting many moons for it to compute).

In Scheme, part of the specification dictates that implementations should indicate whether or not the implementation's internal representation of the number is "exact" or not.  For example, 1/2 is always exact, 1/3 is exact, 0.3333 is exact etc etc.  But the result of an imprecise mathematical operation on an exact number may produce a number that the Scheme implementation knows to be inexact (due to floating point precision).

```
(exact? (/ 0.33333 2))
=> #f
```

That's false, so it's not exact.

Is there a way to deduce the same information in Ruby?  If I always use the `Complex` (or `Rational`) representation of a number during mathematical operations, will it *always* be exact in Ruby, or just extremely close to exact?

```
Complex("0.33333") / 2
```

Is that exact, or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby's class `Float` is [**not exact**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html).  Class `Integer` on the other hand more or less "is" since it shifts seamlessly from `Fixnum` to `Bignum`

```
>> 1.4534346345235236346363574564356435
=> 1.45343463452352
>> 10**400
=> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>> 10.0**400
=> Infinity
```

It looks like others would love to see the test you are asking about, namely `Numeric#exact?` -- see this [feature request](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2571691).

Comment: So basically if I ensure both operands in a mathematical operation (such as a divide) are always instances of Rational or Complex, everywhere I'm doing calculations requiring precision, I'm guaranteed that I'm working with "exact" numbers?  Take-away point, any number in ruby that is *not* a Rational, Complex or Fixnum/Bignum is not exact, even if it's value is `1.7653`, hard-coded as a literal?

Comment: @d11wtq: You might be interested in [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) as well.

Comment: @d11wtq If you have a value of class `Float` it _may_ be exact; for example 2.0 is represented exactly in IEEE 754, but 0.1 is not.  It is theoretically possible to look at a string representation of a float and determine whether there is a representation that is exact but I think that might be hard.  For example 2^-1074 is exactly representable in IEEE 754 double, but that decimal string is huge. :)  Also FWIW, Ruby says Float maps to the "underlying hardware" (not nec. IEEE 754) Bottom line: you are right.  Try to avoid `Float` :) Consider `BigDecimal` described in the link I cited.

Comment: Thanks, although according to that link even BigDecimal is inexact at extremely small values, with no way of actually knowing if the value is truly zero, or just very close to zero.  BigDecimal may return exactly zero, because the result of the operation was too small for it to compute.  I wonder if Rational suffers the same issue.  I know a Rational divided by a Float will be inexact, but what about a Rational divided by an extremely large Rational, such that its value is very close to zero, where BigDecimal falls down.

Comment: Ah, I see, so if BigDecimal.limit(0) is called, that problem is probably avoided.

Comment: I think you might be okay there... Type `Rational(1, 10**500)` into irb. Not sure how computations will proceed from there.  I've never tried it.